Is there a method to decide if a diophantine equation has solutions within a given region?
I constructed an algorithm that requires knowing wether the equation:
$$\frac{x^2}{4}-y^2=n$$
Has integer solutions for a given number $n$ within the region
$$R_n=(2\sqrt{n},n)\times\left(0,\frac{n}{2}\right)$$
With $R_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$; $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. So far, the only method I know about is checking one-by-one for possible answers on a math software, is there another way?

Useful information:
Evidently, we can safely restrict our attention to positive integers; this is, $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$. Also, by simple inspection we can check that any odd number $o\in2\mathbb{N}+1$ will show $\frac{o^2}{4}\notin \mathbb{N}$, so we can further restrict our attention to the region
$$D_n=R_n\cap2\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$$
This is a good thing, since the total number of integer solutions we need to check is effectively halved by considering only even $x$, and restricts our problem to solving a diophantine equation. A solution within the region is not guaranteed, as in the case of $n=7$, whose corresponding region is:
$$R_7=(2\sqrt{7},7)\times\left(0,\frac{7}{2}\right)$$
This can easily be seen by the fact that:
$$D_7=\{(6,0),(6,1),(6,2),(6,3)\}$$
Which, plugged in the given equation, gives respectively: 9,8,5,0; so $R_7$ contains no solution to the diophantine equation.
Finally, if we take in account our new considerations, we can reduce the problem to finding out wether the solution set $S_n$, which equals the intersection of the algebraic variety of an ideal $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x,y], V(I)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $D_n$:
$$S_n=V\left(\langle\frac{x^2}{4}-(y^2+n)\rangle\right)\cap D_n$$
Is not the empty set, this is, $S_n≠\emptyset$.
Thanks in advance!

If $u=x/2$ the equation is  $(u-y)(u+y)=n$ with $(u,y)\in(\sqrt n,n/2)\times(0,\sqrt n).$ This amounts to figuring a factorization $n=AB$ with $A\equiv B\pmod 2$ and $A<\sqrt n<B<n.$ That seems unlikely to have an easier solution than the question finding any non-trivial factorization problem, except when $n\equiv2\pmod 4,$ where we know there are no solutions.

When $n$ is odd, it really is just asserting $n$ is composite. When $n$ is divisible by $4,$ it amounts to asserting $n/4$ is composite.

For example, if $n=8m,$ we can choose $A=4,B=2m,$ and then $u=m+2, y=m-2$ and $x=2m+4,$ which will work for $m$ large.

@ThomasAndrews yes, the algorithm i constructed was a variant of the quadratic sieve. I've optimized it the best I could, but maybe there are some details missing that could make it better. I'll take the specific case you pointed out in account.

Well, the question is really the question "is this prime," since you only want to know if a solution exists. There is a LOT of work on prime checking algorithms, and I don't know any of it beyond the most elementary.

By the way, nowhere in your question did you mention the quadratic sieve. Why not tell us everything you know?

@ThomasAndrews i'm trying to be both concise and polite. Although i would like to express myself in a more free way, MSE is not well known for his friendly approach towards community members.

Let us indeed use the simplified equation $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2=n$ and restrict the domain of search to $\big(\sqrt{n},\tfrac{n}{2}\big)\times\big(0,\tfrac{n}{2}\big)$.
Case 1: $n=4$. This clearly has no solution with $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$.
Case 2: $n=4k$ for some $k\geq 2$. Then the pair $(k+1,k-1)$ is a solution and it lies inside the desired domain.
Case 3: $n$ is even, but not divisible by $4$. Then there can be no solutions, seen by, e.g., checking perfect squares $\mod 2$ or noticing that $x-y\equiv x+y\mod 2$.
Case 4: $n$ is an odd prime. Then, for natural solutions, we must have that $x-y=1$ and $x+y=n$, which leads to the unique solution $\big(\tfrac{n+1}{2},\tfrac{n-1}{2}\big)$, but this is not in the desired domain.
Case 5: $n=p^2$ for some odd prime $p$. We have two options. Either $x-y=1$ and $x+y=n$, which leads to no solutions in the desired domain as before, or $x-y=x+y=p$, which has no solutions over the naturals.
Case 6: $n$ is an odd composite and $n\neq p^2$ for any prime $p$.
Pick an arbitrary divisor $d$ of $n$ such that $2\leq d<\sqrt{n}$. Then the system
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x-y & = d\\
x+y & = \tfrac{n}{d}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
has solution $x=\tfrac{1}{2}\big(\tfrac{n}{d}+d\big)$ and $y=\tfrac{1}{2}\big(\tfrac{n}{d}-d\big)$. By AM-GM inequality, $x>\sqrt{n}$ and it is also easy to see that $x<\tfrac{n}{d}\leq\tfrac{n}{2}$. Also, $y<\tfrac{n}{2}$ is clear too. Since $n$ is odd, $d$ and $\tfrac{n}{d}$ must also be odd, so $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$.
Note that such a divisor $d$ will always exist in this case. So this case will always have a solution in the desired domain.
To summarize, a solution in the desired domain exists if and only if $n$ is divisible by $4$ and at least $8$ or if $n$ is an odd composite number not a square of a prime.

Thanks. Your last case was the kind of proof i was hoping for, and is indeed a solution to the posted question.
